# FATAL EXCEPTION: ZoomTableManager

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm getting a strange crash and I'm having trouble finding anything about it on Google. Searching **ZoomTableManager** returns no results at all.

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: ZoomTableManager
Process: com.xxx.yyy, PID: 22129
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before notify()
        at java.lang.Object.notifyAll(Native Method)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.m.k.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.m.l.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: i am getting same error as well. Using compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42' is this somehow related?

Comment: I am getting same error also.

Comment: I am getting same error after calling same page 4 times on which I am using google map.

Comment: @davis did you fix this error?

Comment: @ShanXeeshi Yes, my problem went away when I fixed the invalid API keys.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Turned out that the cause of the error was an **invalid Google Maps API key**.

Recently we had to change our app's package name and therefore the API keys we used became invalid as you have to specify the allowed apps by signature and package name.

Comment: But i have a valid Google Maps API key. and still happen? please help me

Comment: This is very strange behaviour. I was using invalid Google Map API key since last 2 month it was not crashing app but now I just change bit application flow using invalid Google Map API key. It starts crashing app.  And now I gave valid API Key its working fine again.

Comment: Yep, with the current play store libs, the crash appears when using an invalid key. No crashes after adding correct auth.

Comment: yes, it was happening to me when I used production key for debugging.

Comment: Fixed it for me. I would recommend as well to apply the answer of @Zephyr just in case.

Answer (score 1):

A `IllegalMonitorStateException` with that message happens when you call `obj.notify()` and you aren't holding the primitive mutex for `obj`.

You are supposed to do something like this:

```
    synchronized (someObj) {
        ...
        someObj.notify();
        ...
    }
```

or equivalent, but for some reasons the code that cause the problem has left out the `synchronized` bit.  (Or maybe, it has synchronized on a different object.)

Unfortunately, this is happening in some obfuscated code that provides the Google Maps API implementation.  And you haven't provided any context.  So it is next to impossible for us to even *guess* what is going on.

I suggest that you provide more detail.

Answer (score 0):

The way to fix this problem is to apply for the google map public key for your package.

But the way to **prevent** this crash is to check the return value of the calling `mapFragment = new MapFragment()` and don't call `fm.beginTransaction().replace(id, mapFragment).commit();` if the mapFragment is null.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In our case what changed was the key used to sign the android application (and not the API key).
Before we were using a production key (stored within a keystore). That production key was enabled in Google API Console (https://console.developers.google.com).

We set up a new development environment in a new machine and that machine wasn't using the production key as before, but was using android's default debug key (stored in android's default debug keystore in $HOME/.android/debug.keystore).

The solution was to set up android's default debug key, SHA1 and package name in Google API Console.

1. Get the SHA1:

   keytool -v -list -keystore $HOME/.android/debug.keystore
2. Copy the SHA1: 27:4C:CF:A3:E9:75:4A:59:4C:EE:50:21:2B:1C:7B:48:FC:45:4F:77
3. Go to the Google API Console and enter the SHA1;package name (in APIS & Auth > Credentials > Edit allowed Android applications):

27:4C:CF:A3:E9:75:4A:59:4C:EE:50:21:2B:1C:7B:48:FC:45:4F:77;com.mypackage.name

Enjoy!